# OS X cx_freeze issue with dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: pyqt, python-3.4, cx-freeze, pyqt5, dyld

I developed a Python3.4 + PyQt5 software (Tractotron) on Mac OS X 10.10 (and 10.8 on a VM) and I want to make a standalone executable for mac. 
 I tried both py2app(very far to works for me ...) and cx_freeze. With this last I have an error when I try to launch my app on OS X without Python3.4 :

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python
    Referenced from: /Users/~/Downloads/build/resources/Tractotron
    Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python: 
        no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python: 
       no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

I tried to install cx_freeze with sources in my VM and with macports in my mac but I have always the same error.

I have this setup.py :

```
    # -*-coding:Utf-8 -*
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

    inc_files = ["img"]

    build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os", "sip", "subprocess"], "excludes": ["tkinter"],
        "include_files": inc_files}


    setup(
        name = "Tractotron",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "The Tractotron !",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("interface.py", targetName="Tractotron")],
   )
```

In fact, when I run python3 setup.py bdist_mac the .app generated doesn't work and I use a .command script to call the executable. 
It's ugly but I don't know how to fix the .app. 
I have also tried solutions I found on the net like tool -L and install_name_tool but nothing works ...

Maybe it can help with the result of otool :

```
    otool -L build/exe.macosx-10.10-x86_64-3.4/Tractotron 
    build/exe.macosx-10.10-x86_64-3.4/Tractotron:
        /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.0)
        /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.3.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1151.16.0)
```

I hope someone would help me because I am searching for days to fix that ...

Thank you in advance for the help.

Good evening.